# normal query or sequelize query

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have two tables.

*table 1* has `username`, `designation`, and `report to` in which some users reporting to one user in same table, and their `designation` is mentioned by `id` in that table. `designation` `name` stored in other table named `designations`.

I need above response.. how to achieve it by raw query or sql query..

```
private dataInfo2 = {
'name': 'Kathir',   
'designation':'teamlead',
    'children': [
     {
     'name': 'shift 1',
  designation: empolyee
     },
    {
    'name': 'shift 2',
 designation:employee
   },
]
};
```

Comment: Can you please format your question with actual data models?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table1 in your question is called Employee, a query to get all employees with each employee that reports to them would look like this.

```
SELECT manager.name, manager.designation, employee.name, employee.designation
FROM employee as manager
INNER JOIN employee as employee
 ON managers.id = employees.reportsToEmployeeId
```

You would have to parse the SQL repsonse to JSON in your back-end.

In Sequelize, a query would look like this

```
Employee.hasMany(Employee, {
 as: 'children',
 foreignKey: 'reportsToEmployeeId'
});

const managersIncludingEmployees = models.Employee.findAll({ 
  include: models.Employee
});
```